# protection from Backdoor hacks from disgruntled developer/ employee

Tags: php, mysql, hardening, backdoor, phpmyadmin

I created a ecommerce site with a developer. He completed almost all his work but in the end we had some financial disagreements so our partnership ended in a bitter dispute. That developer threatened to hack my site using a backdoor. To cut long story short, that guy was able to buy products from site without even paying. He bypassed payment processor and bought products. Thankfully i didnt shipped any products to him. Btw i want to clear that i had installed mod security firewall and my server was fairly secure. I hired another developer and he did full code review and found hidden admin account. He told me that my site can be hacked again as he may have left some other backdoors.

So my question is, Are there any good practices that can be used to reduce backdoor damages/hacks. 
The question is not too broad. I want to know basic security practices to protect ourselves from these kind of hacks?

Comment: you need to file a police report. It's likely he committed several felonies gaining unauthorized access, not to mention the attempted theft/fraud. Even if they don't prosecute, they might get a statement from him, which should discourage him from making any more waves.

Comment: the developer is from a foreign country so its useless to file a police report

Answer (score 3):

- For one, contracts. When you have someone develop something, make sure they can't legally add backdoor, so you can sue if they try something.
- Log everything. Backdoors are hard to find in code but you can see where it is after he uses it.
- Have another developer harden the critical parts of your system, that being checkout, order managment and payment processor in your case.

None of these will prevent backdoor access completely, unfortunately it is not possible to prevent completely. You should only collaborate with developers you trust.